# In Azure DevOps, how can I automatically move a Work Item from State to State?

Tags: azure-devops

I have linked a branch to a Task. I want the following to happen automatically:

- Move the Task from `To Do` to `In Progress` when I push the first commit of that branch
- Move the Task from `In Progress` to `Done` when that branch is merged in Main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest feature available in Azure DevOps is the ability to move work items to a particular state based on the content of your commit message.

For example, if you want to move work items to "In Progress" or "Done" you would include something like this in your commit message:

```
In Progress: #1234
Done: #2345
```

However, Azure DevOps only supports this **when a commit is merged**. It won't work for your first use case.

Here's Microsoft's documentation on the feature:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-176-update#customize-work-item-state-when-pull-request-is-merged

Comment: Thanks. I'm very surprised. I would expect this functionality to be fairly standard considering that the branch is already linked to the Work Item (Task). In fact, we shouldn't even have mention that Task# since DevOps is aware of the connection between the Work Item and the branch.

Regardless, I appreciate your answer. :-)

Comment: No problem! I agree, they should have some way to have a more customizable workflow when it comes to work item state automation. The way this feature was implemented did not make the community very happy. They were hoping to get something much like you described. If you're interested in the history of this feature, check out the community feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed/365704